# How to set specified columns into child row so we can increase other columns width in bootstrap datatable?

Tags: datatables

[image: I would like to show these 3 selected columns into child row in my bootstrap datatable.]

I am using bootstrap datatable. I want to show child row control for these selected 3 column. So i can show less info in main grid and i can show full info to user if they want to see.

Generally, in datatable we can show chil row control using "responsive: true".
I want to show data as shown in the below image.

[image]

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by just adding the css.
We just have to set min-width of the column by applying css class.
We have to add media query and based on screen size we can set the width of the columns, so it will automatically set the columns into child row from the right side.